# mod_rewrite rule in .htaccess skips URI in TYPO3

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, typo3

I use this code for redirecting http to https

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www.tronsoeskolen.dk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.tronsoeskolen.dk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it send every page with http to https://frontpage no matter it says after the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite conditions are combined by **AND**, as long as you don't define anything else.
So there is no condition for handling your request without www.

**Your rules do the following:**

If it is not an https request **AND** the request comes not from host https://www.yourdomain.xy, then rewrite to https://www.yourdomain.xy.

**Combine your conditions by [OR] (example):**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
```

This combines the conditions to: if it is not an https request **OR** a request without www.